# Emacs 24: Loading a package installed via ELPA

Tags: emacs, package-management, elpa, cmake

I have just installed the `cmake-mode` package in Emacs 24 using:

```
M-x package-install cmake-mode
```

I can see the package at: `~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824`, and I can load it using the instruction at `Commentary:` section of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824/cmake-mode.el`:

```
;; Add this code to your .emacs file to use the mode:
;;
;;  (setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name "/dir/with/cmake-mode") load-path))
;;  (require 'cmake-mode)
;;  (setq auto-mode-alist
;;        (append '(("CMakeLists\\.txt\\'" . cmake-mode)
;;                  ("\\.cmake\\'" . cmake-mode))
;;                auto-mode-alist))
```

However this contradicts the [usage instruction](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc4) on ELPA's EmacsWiki page:

> ... packages are initialized AFTER the init.el is loaded. This means you should NOT put package specific initialization into your init.el ...

I tend to agree with this instruction because adding to my `~/.gnu-emacs` file a line such as:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824/")
```

is ugly, and will break if and when I will upgrade the package. However without this line I am unable to use `cmake-mode`.

Am I missing something here?

**Notes:**

- I did nothing strange with `package-enable-at-startup` and its' value is `t`.
- I am using [prelude](http://batsov.com/prelude/).
- `user-emacs-directory` value is `"~/.emacs.d/"` *(Thanks @lawlist for the suggestion)*
- `package-user-dir` value is `"~/.emacs.d/elpa"`

Comment: Is it possible you have altered the locations of the `default-directory` or the `user-emacs-directory`, such that the `elpa` directory is not being loaded?  `package-install` creates an `elpa` directory and the autoloads file that is created during the installation is based on that location.

Comment: Your last line of code in your question suggests that you moved the package out of the `elpa` directory -- i.e., `~/.emacs.d/cmake-mode-20110824/` is not where the autoloads file expects it to be.

Comment: @lawlist: You are very observant. I made a mistake in the question. It is now fixed (the question) to the correct value of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824/`. The problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed cmake-mode with the marmalade-repo, and took a look at cmake-mode-autoloads.el.  It appears that the author made a conscious decision `not` include everything needed for the setup within the autoloads file.  However, the instructions on lines 25 to 30 of cmake-mode.el are correct, which you cited in your question.  If you use lines 25 to 30 and set the path correctly, then you do **NOT** need an extra line of code such as `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824/")`.

Obviously, you would not want to use `/dir/with/cmake-mode` -- you want to use `~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824` without a forwardslash at the ending.

```
(setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824") load-path))
(require 'cmake-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("CMakeLists\\.txt\\'" . cmake-mode)
                ("\\.cmake\\'" . cmake-mode))
              auto-mode-alist))
```

You may need to delete the c-make-mode... directory and try reinstalling if the code above does not work (using your own path).

Comment: Sure, but unless I'm missing something, if you later update cmake-mode via ELPA, then either the directory gets renamed to something not in your init file, or the newer version ends up in a directory that's not in your load path; in the latter case, you either don't see the update, or you get undue weirdness because you're manually loading one version and `(package-initialize)` is loading another. Am I wrong? I mean, I haven't used ELPA much and have yet to update any packages with it, so I could be wrong. And, sure, it's not a major concern in any case, but why not avoid it entirely?

Comment: You are correct.  However, the packages don't just update themselves without you knowing about it -- if and when you update, then that would be the time to do your housekeeping.  I frequently invest a substantial amount of time modifying the source files of various packages, and I wouldn't necessarily want them updated after having spent all that time getting them just right.  Emacs is far from what one might consider "maintenance free".

Comment: An excellent point.

Answer (score 3):

Given the wiki's nature as half code repository, half *aide-memoire* for Emacs hackers, you understandably overlooked this point:

> it could be easier just to move package-initialize to another point during startup so you can (require) ELPA packages; this takes care of a lot of the described issues:

This is what I do; one of the first files loaded by my custom init script (the creation of which, from all I can gather, is the *pons asinorum* of serious Emacs use<sup>1</sup>) does

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
```

and from there I simply `(require)` what ELPA packages I need. This also has the benefit of allowing finer control over the behavior of ELPA-installed packages; if, for example, I want to disable a given package for the moment but not uninstall it entirely, it's a simple matter of commenting out the relevant `(require)` call, where the default behavior would require moving the package out of my ELPA directory entirely.

(1. Despite almost overwhelming temptation, I manfully refused to name my custom init script [`lightsaber.el`](http://xkcd.com/297/).)

Comment: Just a reminder to check on *user-emacs-directory* if changed as  ELPA packages reside in there by default. I keep my stuff in Dropbox and I was surprised to see no effect from the above commands in my batch script until I setq it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do all your initialization after packages load using `after-init-hook`. From [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA):

```
;; init.el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (load "<real init file>")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem when I started to use ELPA.
In my case I have had several local packages as those were not present in ELPA.

And thus I had altered load-path. For some reason load-path is not properly updated by package.el.
To solve the problem I had to put `(setq load-path  (cons "~/.emacs.d" load-path))` *after* the call to `package-initialize`