# emacs prefix key and workgroups2

Tags: emacs, workgroup, prefix

I am trying to use workgroups2 which I installed from the builtin emacs package manager elpa. From the readme file:

```
Most commands are bound to both <prefix> <key> and <prefix> C-<key>.

<prefix> <key>
<prefix> c    - create workgroup
<prefix> k    - kill workgroup
<prefix> v    - switch to workgroup
<prefix> C-s  - save session
<prefix> C-f  - load session

Help

Type <prefix> ? (Eval (wg-help)) for more help.

This will bring up a help buffer listing all the commands and their bindings.

See the customization section in the source for details, or use:

M-x customize-group RET workgroups RET
```

Note that I use emacs 24.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

1. What is the prefix key for this situation?

All help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need more information!

**EDIT:** Workgroups2 is not loading when I start emacs. It will not recognize any of the commands. It only works after I have started emacs and if I reload my `.emacs` file and if I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(autoload 'workgroups-mode "workgroups2")
```

How do I get emacs to automatically load workgroups? I would have thought that the above would have sufficed. It is worth noting that I downloaded workgroups2 from melpa and I should not need any of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answering the question

Aaron was right. This line is responsible for the prefix key:

```
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c z"))     ;; and it's by default now
```

So for example - if you want to create a workgroup - press `C-c z c`

### Installation

It's better to compile extension files.

I made installation easier - just install the extension and put these lines somewhere in the **end** of ".emacs". That's all.

```
(require 'workgroups2)
;; change some settings
(workgroups-mode 1)
```

Note that if you use `emacs --daemon` - disable automatic loading of workgroups:

```
(setq wg-use-default-session-file nil)
```

And load them manually (when creating a frame).

## Notes

I checked this extension under Ubuntu (latest Emacs from git repo) and Windows (Emacs 24.3)

**To Aaron:**
Aaron, I've just disabled these remappings by default (I simply didn't face this problem)

**To all:**

1. It's better to [post bugs on Github](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2/issues)
2. (not a real excuse) But please consider that this extension was taken from the experimental branch and most of the code wasn't written by me.
3. If you're a good Emacs hacker - you are always welcome to fix the code and be a collaborator (in order not to repeat the fate of the original repo)

## Test tips

If you want to check only workgroups2 extension:

Assuming you have extracted it under `~/.emacs.d/elisp/extensions/` use this command:

```
emacs -Q -L ~/.emacs.d/elisp/extensions/workgroups2/src -l cl.el -l workgroups2.el --eval '(workgroups-mode 1)'
```

with ido.el:

```
emacs -Q -L ~/.emacs.d/elisp/extensions/workgroups2/src -l cl.el -l ido.el -l workgroups2.el --eval "(ido-mode t)" --eval "(workgroups-mode 1)"
```

Comment: You should check out my other post: http://superuser.com/questions/635013/emacs-workgroups-and-interpreters

Answer (score 2):

The prefix key is defined by the module's user, rather than being specified by the module author. According to [the workgroups2 readme](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2), setting your own prefix key is part of configuring the module:

> ## Configure
>
> Load a module (if you installed it not from Melpa):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/extensions/workgroups2")
(require 'workgroups2)
```

> and set some parameters:

```
;; Settings:
(desktop-save-mode t)     ; save all opened files (or disable it)
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c z")
      wg-restore-associated-buffers nil ; restore all buffers opened in this WG?
      wg-use-default-session-file nil   ; turn off for "emacs --daemon"
      wg-default-session-file "~/.emacs_files/workgroups"
      wg-use-faces nil
      wg-morph-on nil)                  ; animation off

;; Keyboard shortcuts - load, save, switch
(global-set-key (kbd "<pause>")     'wg-reload-session)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<pause>") 'wg-save-session)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-z")         'wg-switch-to-workgroup)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-/")         'wg-switch-to-previous-workgroup)

(workgroups-mode 1)     ; Activate workgroups
```

The line of particular interest here is this one:

```
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c z")
```

This is where the prefix key is defined. Do you have such a line in your Emacs initialization code somewhere? If not, add one, somewhere prior to where workgroups-mode is activated via `(workgroups-mode 1)`, and you should be good to go.

Tested with a fresh install of the workgroups2 package on GNU Emacs 24.3. (And I wish I hadn't, because the stupid thing hijacked `C-x C-<left>` and `C-x C-<right>`!)

Comment: Check out my edit. Workgroups is not loaded when emacs starts and I cannot figure out how to get it too...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Consider [this answer from a similar situation](http://superuser.com/a/631938/162434) -- it's often useful to explicitly call `(package-initialize)` at some point during initialization, so that ELPA packages get loaded before init is finished and can thereafter be managed in the usual fashion.