# emacs workgroups and interpreters

Tags: emacs, window, workgroup

I have installed [workgroups2](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2/blob/master/README.md) from melpa and am trying to configure my ideal workgroups. 
 For my first work group, I wish to have 4 windows. In the first window will by an R script (code written in R) in the window next to it will be an R interpreter. In the 3rd window will be python code and likewise, the window next to it will be a python interpreter.

I created this setting in emacs:[image]

Next, I saved the workgroup and then proceeded to test it. I closed emacs, reopened it and loaded the workgroup. To my surprise, neither of the interpreters were loaded.

1. How can I get both the python interpreter and R interpreter to be saved in a workgroup?
2. Is it possible to save interpreters in workgroups?

Note that I use emacs 24.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called special buffers.  (Not a file or dir to restore)
Right now only default shells, Magit status, Agenda (and a few other buffer types) are restored.

I'm going to dig now to write support for these interpreters.

And you can help:

- what commands do you use to start those buffers (especially R)

We can continue discussion on [Github](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2/issues)

**Update:**

1. Pushed basic support for restoring Python shell

Comment: I have a GitHub account but I have never really used it. I created a new issue and provided the relevant information. Let me know if I am using it correctly. I am very happy to help :)